# Migrating question with an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, migration

The main question that lead to this discussion is: [What does $\mathrm{ms}^{-1}$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60318/1543)

Had I seen the question before there were any answers posted, I would have invoked my moderator powers and migrated it directly to Physics, since a physics question is likely to receive a better answer on a physics site. But when I saw the question, it has already been answered, and an answer had been accepted.

So the question on general policy of *Off-topic questions that were asked with accepted answers*: should we let sleeping dogs lie, or should we close them/boot them to their correct sites?

Comment: From [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8026), I gather that the "accepted" status is maintained post-migration; I thus would love to hear about the cons of performing such a migration. (And a user who was not before registered on the target SE site can flag to have his answer re-associated.)

Answer (score 7):

I think that it's better to let the voting system handle it. I think a (credible) answer is an implicit vote that the question is on-topic. If enough other users vote that the question should be migrated that leaves everyone feeling satisfied, unlike if a moderator migrates the question unilaterally.

Comment: There are two possible objections to this approach: most users in maths have some rudimentary backgrounds in other fields. Just because they can answer a question doesn't mean that it is on topic. Secondly: the migration target of Physics is not open for general 3K+ users, so any such migration has to be performed by a moderator.

Comment: I agree that just because we can answer a question doesn't mean it's on-topic, but if someone does answer the question I think we should let other people vote to migrate it, rather than asking the moderators to decide.

Comment: As to this particular question, I don't think it's more related to physics than to math, because it doesn't seem to be related to anything. I just now voted to close it as not a real question.

Answer (score 4):

As another example: Jeff migrated the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61330/?noredirect=1 to the newly minted crypto.SE even with Paŭlo Ebermann's (he is a moderator *pro tempore* at crypto) note that it might be alright to stay here, given the vote counts for the question. I don't mind the move, but it would have been better to let users vote for migration, no?

Comment: that one seemed like a particularly, unusually good fit for crypto.se -- and it didn't seem that math heavy to me, either

Comment: Hum, to answer one of my own comments to Carl's answer: perhaps what we need is to foster a culture where when a user sees a question as off-topic, but better suited to another site, but said site is *not* yet open as a general migration target, to still vote for closure and leave a flag or a comment about where the question better belongs.

Comment: The migration left behind a dead link?  I though migrations created a forwarding page, but maybe that's only visible to high-rep users?